# how to send value of input in yii2 to controller without submit btn

Tags: ajax, yii2

How I can send value of input(datepicker) to controller, not action. I have some actions, which to need change value of date and I gotta get value of date from datepicker's input. I'm newbie in yii2, and I can't realize it. I found out about sending data by ajax, but ajax sending data only one action(imho). Thanks in advance. (Sorry for my bad English ). At the moment actions works by date().

This is example of my action.

```
public function actionPara_foiz($fac, $cour, $smena, $lesson_id)
{
    if($cour == "")
    {
        if(Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 1, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() != 0 && Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 1, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count() != 0)
        {
            $course1['percent'] = (Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 1, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() / Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 1, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count()) * 100;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
        if(Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 2, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() != 0 && Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 2, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count() != 0)
        {
            $course2['percent'] = (Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 2, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() / Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 2, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count()) * 100;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
        if(Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 3, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() != 0 && Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 3, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count() != 0)
        {
            $course3['percent'] = (Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 3, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() / Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 3, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count()) * 100;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
        if(Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 4, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() != 0 && Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 4, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count() != 0)
        {
            $course4['percent'] = (Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 4, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count() / Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => 4, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count()) * 100;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }

        $courses = [$course1, $course2, $course3, $course4];

        $childPers = array_column($courses, 'percent');

        if(count($childPers) != 0)
        {
            $parentItem['percent'] = array_sum($childPers)/(count($childPers));

            $sum_para1 = $parentItem['percent'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
    }
    else if($cour != "")
    {
        $para1 = Attend::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'lesson_id' => $lesson_id, 'course_id' => $cour, 'shift_id' => $smena, 'attend' => 0, 'date' => date('Y-m-d')])->count();

        $fac_stud_count = Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $fac, 'course_id' => $cour, 'shift_id' => $smena])->count();

        if($fac_stud_count != 0)
        {
            $sum_para1 = $para1/$fac_stud_count *100;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "";
    }
    return $sum_para1;
}
```

this is faculty(view)

```
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
?>
<div class="faculty-index">

    <?php  Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => true]); ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= DatePicker::widget([
        'name' => 'date',
        'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
        'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
        'removeButton' => false,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose'=>true,
            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        ]
        ]);?>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" data-background-color="orange">
            <h4 class="title"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card-content table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="text-warning">
                    <th colspan="12" style="text-align: center;">1-smena</th>
                </thead>
                <thead class="text-warning">
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Fakultet</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Kurslar</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Talabalar soni</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">1-para</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Foizda</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">2-para</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Foizda</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">3-para</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Foizda</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">4-para</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Foizda</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;">Jami foizda</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <?= ListView::widget([
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            'itemView' => '_1smena',
                            'summary'=>'',
                ]) ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is _1smena(_view)

```
<?php 
        $fac_stud_count = Student::find()->where(['faculty_id' => $model->id])->count();
        $smena = 1;
?>
    <tbody style="text-align: center;">

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4"><a href="<?php echo Url::to(['a/c','id'=>$model->id]) ?>"><?= $model->name;?></a></td>
            <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 4; $i++) {?>
            <td><?= $i;?></td>
            <td><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/studentcount', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena]) != 0) { echo Yii::$app->runAction('attend/studentcount', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena]);} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <?php for ($j=1; $j <= 4; $j++) {?>
            <td><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]) != 0) { echo Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]);} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <td id="per_id<?= $j?>_<?= $i;?>"><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para_foiz', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]) != 0) { echo round(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para_foiz', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => $i, 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]), 2)."%";} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <?php }?>
            <td id="res<?= $i;?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">Jami <?= $model->name?></td>
            <td><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/studentcount', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena]) != 0) { echo Yii::$app->runAction('attend/studentcount', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena]);} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <?php for ($j=1; $j <= 4; $j++) {?>
            <td><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]) != 0) { echo Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]);} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <td id="id<?= $j?>"><?php if(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para_foiz', ['fac' => $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]) != 0) { echo round(Yii::$app->runAction('attend/para_foiz', ['fac' =>  $model->id, 'cour' => "", 'smena' => $smena, 'lesson_id' => $j]), 2)."%";} else { echo "";}?></td>
            <?php }?>
            <td id="jami"></td>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var jami1 = document.getElementById ("id1").textContent;
                var jami2 = document.getElementById ("id2").textContent;
                var jami3 = document.getElementById ("id3").textContent;
                var jami4 = document.getElementById ("id4").textContent;
                jami1 = jami1.slice(0, -1);
                jami2 = jami2.slice(0, -1);
                jami3 = jami3.slice(0, -1);
                jami4 = jami4.slice(0, -1);

                jami1 = [Number(jami1)];
                jami2 = [Number(jami2)];
                jami3 = [Number(jami3)];
                jami4 = [Number(jami4)];
                var all = [];

                if(jami1 > 0)
                {
                    all.push(jami1);
                }
                if(jami2 > 0)
                {
                    all.push(jami2);
                }
                if(jami3 > 0)
                {
                    all.push(jami3);
                }
                if(jami4 > 0)
                {
                    all.push(jami4);
                }
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
                  sum += parseInt(all[i]);
                }
                var res = sum/all.length; 

                document.getElementById("jami").innerHTML = res.toFixed(2) + "%";
            </script>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: where is your input(datepicker) in view..?

Comment: oh, sorry. My bad, I added the wrong code. @Gru

Comment: edited. input(datepicker) in faculty(view) @Gru

Comment: So, you wanna display date condition based content on **faculty view**, and **'_1smena'** is your content generator. Am I right..? @Amir Rakhmonov

Comment: @Gru yes. u r right. I wanna when user select some date, content must be change to by date.

Comment: @Gru, Do u have some solutions about that?

Comment: I have one suggestion. 1) Generate data in controller with some default date and pass to view. 2) Whenever you change date; append date to current url & reload current view(by js) 3) In controller, if date Param isset filter dataprovider results or send default date data as per point (1). I hope it will work Amir.

Comment: You can also use `searchModel` to filter expected results (same like search form). A working example link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370026/yii2-listview-search-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with queryParams;

```
$params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
$params[date] // this given value when user request date
```

I don't know, if this is the right decision, but I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using jquery/ajax to obtain when the datetime picker is set and then pass the date data via a post or get request to your controller.

Comment: Can u give some tutorials, examples or info about that, please.  thx in advance.